# Spotify API call returns Internal server error with springTemplate

Tags: spotify, resttemplate

I'm trying to call Spotify API endpoint using spring restTemplate, however, HTTP call returns `Internal server error`.

Is this an issue in Spotify end? Or am I using this API not correctly?

Example:.

```
String API = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBearerAuth(accessToken);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
String url = API + "me/top/artists";
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error

    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpServerErrorException.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
```

I tried same call with same accessToken using curl:

```
>curl -X "GET" -H "Authorization: Bearer accessToken" https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists
>
```

However, this did not return anything (maybe same internal server error?)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the call using `curl` doesn't return anything indicates that the access token you are using might not have all needed scopes authorized. The endpoint `/v1/me/top/{type}` needs `user-top-read` authorized.

Including this scope in your access token should fix the problem.

You can also test this scenario [here](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user-top-artists-and-tracks/).